# Cannot format document in VS code

Tags: xml, formatting, format, visual-studio-code

I tried ctrl+K Ctrl +F, and searching the command palette for "format" but nothing comes up. VS code says Ctrl+K ctrl+f is not a command.

Just upgraded to x64 VS code for windows 10 yesterday. Still not working. File is an XML file that is open from a project. All XML is currently on one line.

Am I missing some extension or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS code Format Code command and shortcut Shift+Alt+F doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776691/vs-code-format-code-command-and-shortcut-shiftaltf-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 7):

You can only use `CTRL+K` `CTRL+F` when you have selected text. Otherwise, if you want to format the whole document, you should use `ALT+Shift+F`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a VS Code extension that provides formatting support for XML.

You can try the [XML Language support by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml), which supports some formatting preferences specific to XML.